# efficient way for writing to list of lists made from matrix

Tags: python, matrix, memory, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to fill parts of sparse lil matrix from another with this code:

```
adj_mat = sp.dok_matrix((self.n_users + self.m_items, self.n_users + self.m_items), dtype=np.float32)
adj_mat = adj_mat.tolil()
R = self.UserItemNet.tolil()
```

When I try to fill that with this code:

```
adj_mat[:self.n_users, self.n_users:] = R
adj_mat[self.n_users:, :self.n_users] = R.T
```

My process is killed, because of exceeding RAM memory (240Gi).
My dataset is big:

`adj_mat`:

```
<1374194x1374194 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
with 0 stored elements in List of Lists format>
```

`R`:

```
<940696x433498 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 24053124 stored elements in List of Lists format>
```

`self.n_users` = 940696

Is there some more efficient way to fill list of lists like that?

Best regards

Comment: We'd have to study how it does the copy from one `lil` to the other.  Too bad it was a kill as opposed to memory error message.   It would be nice to know how far it got.  Did it succeed with the first copy?  Was the `R.T` a problem?  Was it in the 2nd copy.  Unfortunately this is not the kind of thing that I want to test on my computer - I don't like hanging processes.  Plus my memory is much smaller.

Comment: Actually, the first line kills that process. I don't know how far it went, but I tried to do that on half of my data - it has also failed. Only 1/10 of my data went through with that code.

Comment: List of list is a horrifyingly inefficient way to store data. Don't ever use it for any reason. Use COO instead.

Comment: Digging through the `lil` `__setitem__` code, it ends up using `__set_arrayXarray_sparse`, but that does a "# Fall back to densifying x".  In other words, it doesn't try figure out how to copy the nonzero values of `R` to `adj_mat`, but rather does a `R.toarray()` and make a "regular" assignment.  So densifying `R` is probably causing the memory error.

Comment: @CJR, I suspect he's using `lil` because it's supposed to be best for index assignment.  `coo` doesn't do indexing.  I'm not sure that the `lil` format is any worse for memory use than `coo`.  That `csr` is better than `coo` for most matrices is well known.  But here I think the issue is the default `setitem` route.

Comment: What's the original format of `R`?  It might be better to make `adj_mat` via `sparse.bmat`,   `bmat` takes the `coo` attributes of the component matrices, and makes a new `coo` matrix with appropriate offsets.  `R.T` for `csr` format is trivial (just a `csc`).  Or we might do a custom `coo` creation inspired by `bmat`.

Comment: Lil is so much worse for memory then coo - every single number, both index and values, is a python object - so there's a massive ton of overhead. COO is backed by arrays at least. I definitely would come up with a better way to build what you want then lil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `bmat` approach to constructing your composite matrix (assuming I've deduced the correct layout):

Make a matrix.  `bmat` will combine `coo` attributes, so lets start with that:

```
In [389]: R = sparse.coo_matrix([[0,1],[2,0],[0,0],[3,4]])
In [390]: R
Out[390]: 
<4x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [391]: R.A
Out[391]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [3, 4]])
```

And define the 'blank' filler matrices:

```
In [392]: Z1 = sparse.coo_matrix((4,4),dtype=int)
In [393]: Z2 = sparse.coo_matrix((2,2),dtype=int)
```

Now join them:

```
In [394]: M = sparse.bmat([[Z1,R],[R.T,Z2]])
In [395]: M
Out[395]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 8 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [396]: M.A
Out[396]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4],
       [0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]])
```

This will avoid the densification that the default assignment apparently does.

`block_diag` uses the other diagonal:

```
In [398]: sparse.block_diag([R,R.T])
Out[398]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 8 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [399]: _.A
Out[399]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4]])
```

This `block_diag` code would be a good model if you want to write your own version.  The v1.6 release notes claims it is much more efficient than the previous version (which I believe worked through `bmat`).

### assignment efficiency

In response to @CJR's comments about `lil` memory inefficiency, I looked at some alternatives.

Make a large `coo` matrix:

```
In [10]: M=sparse.random(10000,10000, .2, 'coo')
```

Conversion to `lil` is slower than conversion to `csr`:

```
In [11]: timeit M.tocsr()
1.43 s ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [12]: timeit M.tolil()
3.69 s ± 10.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So how does the block assignment compare? (using a much smaller block than the OP):

```
In [13]: Ml=M.tolil(); Mr=M.tocsr()

In [14]: timeit Ml[:100,:100]=np.eye(100)
1.07 ms ± 341 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [15]: timeit Mr[:100,:100]=np.eye(100)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:125: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_arrayXarray(i, j, x)
14.1 ms ± 144 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`csr` assignment is quite a bit slower, while `coo` assignment doesn't even work.

```
In [16]: timeit M[:100,:100]=np.eye(100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ....
TypeError: 'coo_matrix' object does not support item assignment
```

So if you must to block assignment, `lil` isn't a bad choice, provided the blocks aren't too big.  But constructing the matrix directly from blocks via `bmat` is a better.  As the `lil` docs say, use `coo` if you are constructing large matrices.

Comment: I've made it with bmat and it works! Thank you for your help.